# StringBuilder Class in C++ not working properly

Tags: c++, string, class

I'm working on an assignment to create a class called StringBuilder that is used for fast string concatenation. I'm supposed to store strings in a dynamic array and have methods such as Append(string) which adds a new string to the dynamic array. The method I'm currently struggling with is GetString() that creates a single string on the heap that is the length of all the strings in the dynamic array that have been added thus far.

the code I have so far is:

okay my main problem is my GetString() function prints out hello over and over again until I force quit the program in Xcode. I don't understand what inside that method is making that happen.

My header file:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
 
using namespace std;
 
class StringBuilder
{
public:
    StringBuilder();
    //~StringBuilder();
    void GetString();
    void AppendAll(string*, int);
    void Length();
    void Clear();
    void Append(string userString);
    void DoubleArray(string*& allWords, int newCapacity);
    
     
private:
    string* p_array;
    int capacity = 5;
   
};
```

my .cpp file :

```
#include "StringBuilder.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

----------
    
void StringBuilder::Append(string userString)
{
    
    int nextWordPosition = 0;
    
    
    for(int i=0; i < capacity ; i++)
    {
        p_array[i]  = userString;
        cout << p_array[i] << endl;
        nextWordPosition +=1;
        if(capacity == nextWordPosition)
        {
            capacity *=2;
            DoubleArray(p_array, capacity * 2);
        }
    }
    
   
    nextWordPosition++;
}

void StringBuilder::DoubleArray(string*& allWords, int newCapacity)
{
    string* p_temp = new string[newCapacity];
    for(int i =0; i < newCapacity / 2; i++)
    {
        p_temp[i] = allWords[i];
    }
    
    delete[] allWords;
    allWords = p_temp;

}

void StringBuilder:: GetString()
{
   
    for(int i=0; i < capacity ; i++)
    {
        
        cout << p_array[i]<< endl;
        
    }
}
```

my main.cpp file :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "StringBuilder.hpp"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    
    string testString = "hello";
    string test = "world!";
    StringBuilder Builder1;
    
    Builder1.Append(testString); 
    Builder1.Append(test);
    
    Builder1.GetString(); 
    
    return 0;
    
}
```

Comment: You've not explained the problem you're having with your code, or asked a specific question. Please [edit] your post to address those issues.

Comment: *that is used for fast string concatenation.* -- I don't see any speed improvement in your code -- a  simple wrapping of a `std::vector<std::string>` in a class would be fast, if not faster.  More than likely, your code makes things slower.

Comment: Take a look at `Append` right after `if(capacity == nextWordPosition)`. `capacity` is doubled then passed as a parameter where it is doubled again. Then `for(int i =0; i < newCapacity / 2; i++)` uses half the value which seems like it would go right off the end of the allocated space since the value is 4 times the original capacity. Is `GetString()` supposed to return a string or print the strings? If you want to combine them consider using a `stringstream`.

Comment: When formatting code the 3 backticks need to be on a line by themselves and you shouldn't also indent the code inside them 4 spaces. Pick one or the other..

Comment: I'm not allowed to use vectors for this assignment as specified by my professor

Comment: GetString() is supposed to print the strings to the console

Comment: You need to provide a [mre] and debugging details. Anyway, the Append() method have a weird infinite loop.

Comment: @KelsieB -- *I'm not allowed to use vectors for this assignment* -- Before anyone else posts an answer that may get rejected -- what else are you not allowed to use?  Remember that when you post a question on StackOverflow, you will get comments and answers geared to everything that may be possible in the C++ language.  We have no idea what your professor has told you.  You should specify *up front* what you can or cannot use.